# how can set a default value for MultiSelectField of a django model

Tags: django, django-models

```
from django.db import models

from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField

class Shop(models.Model):

DAYS = (
    ('sunday', 'Sunday'),
    ('monday', 'Monday'),
    ('tuesday', 'Tuesday'),
    ('wednesday', 'Wednesday'),
    ('thursday', 'Thursday'),
    ('friday', 'Friday'),
    ('saturday', 'Saturday'),
    ('Not any day', 'None'),
       )

closingDay = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS)
```

[click here to get picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MT9yV.png)
Note: when I put the (default=DAYS[7][7]) inside the closingDay. Its showing 
tuple index exceeded the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are assigning **default=DAYS[7][7]** you are assigning the value of 8th column of 8th row, which obviously does not exist.
you should assign ***default=DAYS[7][0]***

Comment: sorry bro it is not working...I think its because of MultiSelectField

Comment: can you please post the traceback ?

Comment: after puttting default=[7][0] server is still running I migrated also but not working (still not taking any default value) if you have any idea about MultiSelectField be concerned about it.. because it is imported from a package multiselectfield

Comment: I tried your code. and it is working for me. It is not showing anything template maybe because **DAYS[7][0]** refer to None. I checked this in admin and by default None is checked. Let me know if you are getting the same.

Comment: Dear sumit kumar can u plzzz post the snap of ur model and admin plzzz.....??
Actually it shows while adding a new Shop

Comment: I am not using this in any template, i am just checking it through admin if it is taking this value or not.
[Screenshots](https://imgur.com/a/8Kc4q)

Answer (score 2):

It's easy actually, `MultiSelectField` accepts either array of strings or single string as `default`.

Some of the valid values that work in this example would be.

```py
#Using choice value
closingDay = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS, default=DAYS[7][0])
#Multiple value default
closingDay = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS, default=['sunday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday'])
#Direct String
closingDay = MultiSelectField(choices=DAYS, default='thursday')
```